# Ajax.beginform redirecting after replacing targetid in IE 8/7 MVC2

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Why is IE behaving like this? It works fine on Chrome and firefox so i got this in

view.ascx

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action1", "TheController", new { pid= Request.QueryString["pid"] }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "setting-modal-body", OnSuccess = "fnPreloadAttr" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "setting-edit-form" }))
                   {%>
                <div id="setting-modal-body" class="clearfix">
                    <%Html.RenderPartial("SettingModal"); %>
                </div>
                <%}   %>
```

TheController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Action1(SettingModel setModel)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
setModel.Aa="1";                
                return PartialView("SettingModal", setModel);
            }
```

it works fine and replacing the content of setting-modal-body but shortly after that IE redirect the page to Action1 because of 'onload' event, how to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving up on using ajax.beginform, it just doesn't return false after onsubmit is done, so I use this instead

```
  <form action="/TheController/Action1?pid=<%=Request.QueryString["pid"] %>" class="form-horizontal" id="setting-edit-form" method="post" onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'POST', updateTargetId: 'setting-modal-body', onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, fnPreloadAttr) });return false;">
```

mvc2 ajax is not good